# Was ist ein "Eselsbänkler"?

Tags: meaning

Siehe Titel. Das Wort ist mir in der deutschen Übersetzung von John le Carrés  "Tinker Tailor Soldier Spy" begegnet.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Die *[Eselsbank](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Eselsbank)* war früher in der Schule die Schulbank, an die der Lehrer die hoffnungslosen Fälle gesetzt hat - entweder ganz vorne oder (eher) ganz hinten im Klassenzimmer.

Der *Eselsbänkler* ist dann eben derjenige, der dorthin verbannt wurde.

Comment: Das [bayerische Schulmuseum](https://www.schulmuseum.org)  zeigt laut ihrer Internetseite  einem Raum  mit Eselsbank: https://www.schulmuseum.org/raeume/ (ganz unten im Abschnitt 'In weiteren Räumen')

Comment: Dabei mußte ich sogleich an den Thomas-Esel denken! https://www.wp.de/staedte/kreis-olpe/tagebuch-eines-esels-id10217017.html

Answer (score 6):

Das Wort stammt aus den finsteren Zeiten deutscher Pädagogik. Dumme Schüler wurden vom Lehrer als "Esel" bezeichnet und mussten auf der "Eselsbank" sitzen. Wenn der Übersetzer eines englischen Textes diesen Begriff gewählt hat, muss der Autor wohl ähnliche Praktiken beschrieben haben.

Comment: Ich würde mir Zitate wünschen. Kommt das Wort irgendwo im Schrifttum des, sagen wir, 19. Jahrhunderts vor?

Answer (score 2):

Somebody sitting on the dunces' bench.